# how to send Json file to kafka from Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, apache-kafka

I have a json file like below which I want to send to kafka from python.

**Json File**

```
 filename = 'External_Risk_{}.json'.format(date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    d =df.to_json(filename, orient='records')
```

**Sending to Kafka**

```
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient
import json 
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer =KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
jd = json.dumps(d)
producer.send_messages(b'message1',jd)
```

But it not working . What is correct way of sending a json file to Kafka.

Comment: Why are you using pandas? If you have a dataframe, you should be sending each row separately, not the whole thing at once

Comment: @cricket_007,  the expected output inside kakfa is json and I am creating the json after many data manipulations using pandas. So should I be using your method to send the dataframe to kakfa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be asking how to load a file to a string, then you're just sending a string to Kafka

```
import json 
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer =KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')

with open(filename) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    producer.send_message(topic, data.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import json

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})

p.produce('topic', json.dumps({"demo": "message"}))
```

Comment: install confluent kafka using  pip install confluent-kafka

Comment: not its the topic on kafka on which you want to dump the json message.

Comment: like from your example 'message1' is the topic

Comment: in my case ,How do I adapt your code, I am saving json file to`d`

Comment: just put p.produce('topic', jd) as you already have json dump in 'jd' variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a dict by simply doing like that:

```py
producer = KafkaProducer(
    acks='all',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    value_serializer=lambda v: bytes(json.dumps(v, default=str).encode('utf-8'))
)
```

I call bytes() method before returning the json in the lambda